# Removing duplicate Sets from List

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to remove duplicate Set of custom objects from ArrayList. Below is the code I have written which uses toString representation of custom EmployeeObj to compare. Can you please suggest what other approaches can be taken?

```
package com.collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class DupSetInsideList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Set<EmployeeObj>> list = new ArrayList<Set<EmployeeObj>>();

        Set<EmployeeObj> set1 = new HashSet<EmployeeObj>();
        Set<EmployeeObj> set2 = new HashSet<EmployeeObj>();
        Set<EmployeeObj> set3 = new HashSet<EmployeeObj>();

        list.add(set1);
        list.add(set2);
        list.add(set3);

        EmployeeObj empObj1 = new EmployeeObj(1, "Nikhil");
        EmployeeObj empObj2 = new EmployeeObj(2, "Rakesh");
        EmployeeObj empObj3 = new EmployeeObj(3, "Kunal");

        set1.add(empObj1);
        set1.add(empObj2);

        set2.add(empObj1);
        set2.add(empObj2);

        set3.add(empObj1);
        set3.add(empObj2);
        set3.add(empObj3);

        System.out.println("List with duplicaes: " + list);
        //Output: List with duplicaes: [[1=Nikhil, 2=Rakesh], [1=Nikhil, 2=Rakesh], [3=Kunal, 1=Nikhil, 2=Rakesh]]

        //Remove duplicates
        List<Set<EmployeeObj>> nonDupList = new ArrayList<Set<EmployeeObj>>();
        for(Set<EmployeeObj> obj1:list) {
            if(!nonDupList.contains(obj1)) {
                nonDupList.add(obj1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List without duplicates: " + nonDupList);
        //List without duplicates: [[1=Nikhil, 2=Rakesh], [3=Kunal, 1=Nikhil, 2=Rakesh]]
    }
}

class EmployeeObj {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public EmployeeObj(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EmployeeObj other = (EmployeeObj) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + "=" + name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just implement equals and hashcode? That way java will be able to see if 2 objects are equal by default.

Comment: the problem is that he needs to override the equals and hashCode on the HashSet object.

Comment: Hello Kurt, Funtik is right, its a kind of nested objects. We need to compare Set of elements which is inside ArrayList.

Comment: To have this information here as well: equals() and hashCode() of Set are specified to have a behavior that makes overriding them unnecessary in this case: Two sets are equal if they have the same size and contain the same elements (regardless of the order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
private boolean equals(Set elements, Set elements2) {
    return elements != null && elements.equals(elements2);
}

private List<Set> removeDuplicates(List<Set> from) {
    List<Set> noDuplicates = new ArrayList<Set>();

    for (Set possibleDuplicate : from) {
        boolean alreadyInNoDuplicatesList = false;
        for (Set elementFromNoDuplicateList : noDuplicates) {
            if (equals(elementFromNoDuplicateList, possibleDuplicate)) {
                alreadyInNoDuplicatesList = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!alreadyInNoDuplicatesList) {
            noDuplicates.add(possibleDuplicate);
        }
    }

    return noDuplicates;
}
```

Comment: your equals is broken as `equals([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])` would return true. You would have to test in both ways or test one way and compare the size.

Comment: Thanks for writing Funtik, but do you think custom objects in the Set will be taken care of in your equals(Set, Set) method?

Comment: @Funtik Why don't you simply do `return elements.equals(elements2);` in your equals method? (with null checks to be complete)

Comment: @NikhilJoshi they will be, if you override equals and hashCode in them

Comment: @ZouZou another good point. Shame on me, I did not consider that simple option. Will edit the answer. Thank you

Comment: @Funtik Just `elements != null && elements.equals(elements2);` is enough.

Comment: @ZouZou, yeah, you're right again. Thank you, master

Comment: Funtik, you are right, overriding equals() and hashCode() on custom objects will be sufficient.

Comment: Can anybody enlighten me why this solution should be considered as acceptable? That is (apart from things like raw types being used) : Why is a for-loop used to manually check whether an element is 'alreadyInNoDuplicatesList', when one could simply write `noDuplicates.contains(possibleDuplicate)`? And why does one use an method with O(n^2) when there is a simple, one-line O(n) solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list behaviour guaranteeing a uniqueness of elements use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

If you are bound to using `ArrayList` (as in a student exercise), extend it, overwrite `add` and `addAll` methods by checking the uniqueness first and then calling `super.add` resp. `super.addAll` and then use the new class in place of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yeah, LinkedHashSet can be used to maintain the insertion order. But here List is already built using HashSet element, and from this we need to remove duplicates.

Comment: If you are question is about keeping the uniqueness of sets in your outer structure, list, then it does not matter that they are already in a list: `new LinkedHashSet<>(array_of_sets)` will eliminate the duplicates in exactly the same way. If this is not what you are after, then please consider reformulating your question: maybe post an outline of your algorithm rather than a relatively length code.

Comment: Hello Oleg, thank you for quick response. I am trying to say that -- HashSet inside a ArrayList is pre-defined non-changeble requirement -- I am just trying to figure out the different approaches by which it can be done.

Comment: Got it, see my edit to the answer. But generally given your requirements you have a reasonable solution (i.e. populating the list conditionally) and it feels like any other one would be more complex (given the bounds of using `ArrayList`).

Answer (score 1):

The `Set` interface specifies the `equals` method as follows:

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set).

So in order to create a list that contains no duplicates (even if the elements in the list are sets), one can simply write

```
    //Remove duplicates
    List<Set<EmployeeObj>> nonDupList = 
        new ArrayList<Set<EmployeeObj>>(
            new LinkedHashSet<Set<EmployeeObj>>(list));
```

Comment: This is superb solution, really coolest. :-) However -- HashSet inside a ArrayList is pre-defined non-changeble requirement -- I am just trying to figure out the different approaches by which it can be done.

Comment: You should probably describe this requirement more clearly. If the Sets are HashSets, then this requirement will be fulfilled by the code that I posted. The fact that you don't see them as HashSets (but only as Sets) is caused by the fact that you don't see them as HashSets in the originally posted code!

Comment: I agree, though your answer adds up more information in my bag. I will make sure that next time question will be more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Sets in a Set and they'll be removed as if by magic!

Comment: Hello Kayaman, yeah you are right. I forgotten to mention that how can we re-invent the wheel? I know its not required, but just for the learning purpose.

Comment: @Funtik equals() and hashCode() of Set are specified to have a behavior that makes overriding them unnecessary in this case: Two sets are equal if they have the same size and contain the same elements (regardless of the order)  EDIT: Kayaman: +1 for that - it was already the correct answer!

Comment: @Marco13, yes, mr. ZouZou has already enlightened me in this regard.